# If $E,F$ are measurable is it true that $m(E\cap (F+t))$ is a continuous function in $t$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So I know that $t\mapsto m(E\cap (-\infty,t])$ is a continuous function if $E$ is measurable as $\bigcap(-\infty,t_n] = (-\infty,t]$ if $t_n\downarrow t$, but I'm wondering if $t\mapsto m(E\cap (F+t))$ is continuous.

Comment: Would you write out why you think the proof for the first function doesn't apply to the second?

Comment: $\bigcap F+t_n $ could be a proper subset of $F+t$.

Comment: Is $m$ an arbitrary measure?

Comment: It's the Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can firstly assume that $F$ is contained in compact set, and $F$ can not contained in an interval $I$, Then we have $$(t_2+F)\Delta(t_1+F)\subset (t_2+I)\Delta(t_1+I)$$

It implies that

$$m((t_2+F)\Delta(t_1+F))\leq m((t_2+I)\Delta(t_1+I))$$
which implies that your function is continuous.

For general case. we first prove that $m(F\cap K^c)$ under the assumption that $m(F)< \infty$. And then we argue it on $F\cap K$. Here $K$ is a compact set you choose.